# Validacion inicio de sesion con PHP / Postgresql PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, login, validación

Estoy trabajando con un formulario de inicio de sesion en html / PDO PHP. Como mis conocimientos PDO son casi ceros he ido avanzando en lo que la logica me indica y con stackoverflow. Ya hice mi conexion y captura de datos y valido la información (repito como la logica me ha indicado, logica de principiante) pero tengo un problema cuando la pagina carga me activa una alerta de validación y no encuentro como hacer para que solo se active cuando envie el formulario, lamentablemente no puedo trabajar la validación en un archivo a parte, a continuación el codigo:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include ('pdoconnectexpo.php');
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['pwd'];

if(isset($_POST['iniciar_sesion'])){
$query = 'SELECT id_usuario, usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena=:contrasena';
//Usuario
$registros = $conn2->prepare( $query ); //Preparamos la consulta
$registros->execute( array(":usuario" => $usuario,":contrasena" => $contrasena) ); //Le pasamos el valor al marcador, esto es un array por lo que soporta tanto valores requiera la query, separador por coma
$registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); //convirtiendo el resultado en objetos para poder iterar en un ciclo.
if(!isset($registros[0]->usuario)){
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Usuario Errado o Contraseña Errada\");</script>";
}else{
// code...
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
header('Location: inicio.php');
}
}

?>
```

Y debajo del php llamo el siguiente codigo html(solo coloco el formulario):

```html
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34">
      Inicio de Sesión
     </span>

     <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Type user name">
      <input id="first-name" class="input100" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="wrap-input100 rs2-wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Type password">
      <input class="input100" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Contraseña">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <button class="login100-form-btn">
       Iniciar Sesión
      </button>
     </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es que puedes optimizar tu consulta en vez de 2 tener 1;

```
session_start();
include ('pdoconnectexpo.php');
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['pwd'];
/*echo $usuario;
echo $contrasena;*/
$query = 'SELECT usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena = :contrasena';
//Usuario
$registros = $conn2->prepare( $query ); //Preparamos la consulta
$registros->execute( array(":usuario" => $usuario,":contrasena" => $contrasena) ); //Le pasamos el valor al marcador, esto es un array por lo que soporta tanto valores requiera la query, separador por coma
$registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); //convirtiendo el resultado en objetos para poder iterar en un ciclo.


if(!isset($registros[0]->usuario)){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Usuario Errado o Contraseña Errada\");</script>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
    header('Location: inicio.php');
}
```

Entonces en tu `HTML` en el boton de iniciar sesión créalo de tipo `submit` y asignarle un nombre con el atributo `name`, de esta manera verificas que ese botón sea pulsado;

```
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
  <input type="submit" name="iniciar_sesion" class="login100-form-btn" value="Iniciar Sesión">
</div>
```

> Nota: solo te agrege el boton de html.

Con esto solo queda verificar que cuando el boton sea pulsado esto muestre la alerta;

```
if(isset($_POST['iniciar_sesion'])){
    //todo tu codigo de inicio se sesion aqui
}
```

combinando todo esto te queda así;

```
if(isset($_POST['iniciar_sesion'])){

$query = 'SELECT usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena = :contrasena';
//Usuario
$registros = $conn2->prepare( $query ); //Preparamos la consulta
$registros->execute( array(":usuario" => $usuario,":contrasena" => $contrasena) ); //Le pasamos el valor al marcador, esto es un array por lo que soporta tanto valores requiera la query, separador por coma
$registros = $registros->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ); //convirtiendo el resultado en objetos para poder iterar en un ciclo.


if(!isset($registros[0]->usuario)){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Usuario Errado o Contraseña Errada\");</script>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
    header('Location: inicio.php');
}
    //todo tu codigo de inicio se sesion aqui
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34">
    Inicio de Sesión
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Type user name">
        <input id="first-name" class="input100" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input100 rs2-wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-20" data-validate="Type password">
        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="iniciar_sesion" class="login100-form-btn" value="Iniciar Sesión">
    </div>

</form>
```

Te explico un poco mas, lo que hicimos fue crear un nuevo elemento de tipo input, para enviarlo al servidor cuando el usuario envié el formulario así comprobamos que este elemento exista en la petición de datos al servidor y podemos estar seguro de que esto solo se carga cuando el formulario es enviado por `POST.`

Comment: Eso mismo era, muchas gracias!

Comment: Solo tengo un problemita con el codigo, que no me esta tomando el id_usuario en la variable de inicio de sesión, a que se deberá?

Comment: Debes verificar que el código este completo ya que no veo de donde viene la variable `$id_usuario`

Comment: Modifique el código en este post segun tus recomendaciones, funciona perfecto solo el tema de la variable de inicio de sesion que no se como capturarla desde PDO, estoy tratando de capturarla con un SELECT en sql.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz prueba colocando `if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){ echo "existe la variable de sesion id_usuario";}else{echo "no existe la sesion"};` de esta manera probaras la existencia de dicha variable, pero vuelvo y te recarco, no logro ver en tu codigo de donde viene la variable `$id_usuario`

Comment: Lo que mi ignorancia me dice es que estoy tomando del select id_usuario dicho campo y lo estoy almacenando en una variable de session $_SESSION['id_usario'] y a su vez esta variable la almaceno en $id_usuario.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz ahora si, entonces modifica tu query a lo siguiente `'SELECT usuario,id_usuario FROM "public".usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena = :contrasena';` de esta manera estas selecionando el ID en la query.

Comment: Ya modifiquè el codigo, verificalo arriba, asì esta pero no me lo carga.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz ahora asignarle valor a tu sesión `$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $registros[0]->id_usuario`

Comment: Ahora si. Muchas gracias man, eres un crack!